# WPF MVVM Databinding Textbox dependency overwriting input or not updating input

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This has to be a common problem with a solution for this, but I cannot find it.
I need to be able to set a value in the textbox, but the textbox is often updated by an outside source (PLC in this case). When it is updated from the source, I want to display the updated value in the textbox (not when the user is typing however) without calling a method being called from the setter of the dependency property.

I have a basic textbox that is bound to a dependency property in the view model xaml code.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding A}" />
```

The property looks like this

```
private string _a;
public string A
get
        {
            return _a;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _a)
            {
                Set(ref _a, value);
                SomeMethod(value);
            }
        }
```

From here I have tried updating the field

```
_a = ValueFromAnotherSource;
```

Which does not update the view unless I run

```
RaisePropertyChanged(String.Empty);
```

In which case the user input when typing is overwritten if the value updates.

Alternatively I can write to the property

```
A = ValueFromAnotherSource;
```

But the SomeMethod(value) gets called which is not something I want, this should only be called when the value is changed from the user typing on the screen

Comment: The function `Set` triggers `NotifyPropertyChanged`, right?

Comment: This will never work in a satisfying manner. Imagine the user leaves the input focus in the TextBox forever. It will never show an upated value from the view model. You actually need two UI elements, one for input and one for output.

Comment: The binding sourceupdated event could be used to drive when data transfers from the textbox to viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the coding standard Gods will smite me for this:

```
private string _a;
private bool _manuallySettingA;
public string A
{
    get { return _a; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _a)
        {
            Set(ref _a, value);
            if(!_manuallySettingA)
                SomeMethod(value);
        }
    }
}

public void ManuallySetA(string value)
{
    _manuallySettingA = true;
    A = value;
    _manuallySettingA = false;
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something along these lines where I used the EventToCommand from xmlns:Custom="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight" x:Class="RAMware3.TabView.TabSetupSetup2" to setup a relay command that called the function that would be ManuallySetA which looked for a bool set if the value of A was actually updated.

Answer (score -1):

Use different method which is called when update comes from other source than user input. I.e.

```
void SetA(string value)
{
  if (value != _a)
  {
      Set(ref _a, value);
  } 
}
```

You will be able to distinguage whether  call was from user or other source.

And you will not call `SomeMethod` when _a needs to be updated from other sources.

Of course `SetA` will update UI value  if your mentioned `Set(ref _a, value)` method rises PropertyChanged event.